# QOpenGLWidget cannot display on some windows 10 machine

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I used `QOpenGLWidget` in my qt software to draw some pictures.
But I found that in some windows 10 machine, when I used `QOpenGLWidget`, then the GUI's all widget cannot display, the GUI's background is white。
I have not do any modify of `QOpenGLWidget`。
Why have this problem?

Comment: please share some of your code, or explain it more

Comment: In fact I just add the widget by QT designer,and then build the project.So I do not have add any my source code.all the code is auto generated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please, note, that appropriate answers are easier to achieve if an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is provided.

Comment: Btw. Qt provides some nice (simple but complete) [OpenGL Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html). You may try them whether they reproduce the wrong behavior. If yes: probably something is wrong with the installation of your Windows 10 PCs. (We once had such a case where the NVidia driver update failed and the system felt back to some generic default driver. We just noticed it because our Qt OpenGL application failed.) If not: probably something is wrong with your application (even, though you just clicked something together in Qt Designer). Hard to say w/o any code...